# ExtJS 4 - Create model that contains List of list

Tags: extjs4

I have one specific problem to create Model for my ExtJs 4 MVC application. Model should read JSON that is something like this
Version Number: 1
Image Names:
                Image 1
                Image 2
                ...
                Image N
Set 1:
                URL1
                URL2
                ...
                URLN
Set 2:
                URL1
                URL2
                ...
                URLN
...

Set M:
                URL1
                URL2
                ...
                URLN

I'm thinking about associations but here we have one global object and this list of list.
Does anybody have some idea how to define this model.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From my experience there isn't a straightforward built-in way of keeping an array of strings in a model. You can use associations as you said, but then your JSON is expected to have an array of objects instead of strings:

```
{
    "urls": [{"url":"www.google.com"}, {"url","www.yahoo.com"}],
    "images": [{"img":"image1.png"}, {"img","image2.png"}]
}
```

What I usually do if I don't need the extra functionality provided by associations, is just return my lists as a string with a delimiter. (I usually use pipe)

```
{
    "urls": "www.google.com|www.yahoo.com",
    "images": "image1.png|image2.png"
}
```

Then if I need to do any processing on them I just have to call .split('|') and I have an array. And if I need to display them somewhere, I just set up a renderer function.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I was trying to figure out the same issue and stumbled on an incredibly simple solution - just set the list as a 'text' field type and if the json data is in standard list format for json (e.g. "urls" : ["www.google.com", "www.yahoo.com"]) it just moves it over as a string array by default - simple.   Skips associations altogether if that complexity isn't needed.   Access resulting 'urls' field as a string array.

Works on write as well.  Very happy.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't List of Lists a Tree? You can use a Tree

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/tree/two-trees.html